# Disable element attribute before onclick function is executed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to disable double clicking buttons using directives in Angular.

Here is my relevant template code:

```
<button (click)="onClickFunction()" appPreventDoubleClick>Add</button>
```

Here is my directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appPreventDoubleClick]"
})
export class PreventDoubleClickDirective {
  count: number = 0;
  constructor() {}

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  click(event) {
    ++this.count;
    if (this.count > 1) {
      console.log("disabling");
      event.srcElement.setAttribute("disabled",true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        event.srcElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
        this.count = 0;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm basically trying to do is disable a button if it's clicked twice and reset it after 1 second so that `onClickFunction()` won't be called if it is disabled. But what's happening is that although the `@HostListener click()` function is being called before `onClickFunction()`, `onClickFunction()` is still executing. How can I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: As per the comment, I wanted to mention that I had tried this first:

```
@HostListener("click", ["$event"])
click(event) {
  event.srcElement.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    event.srcElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }, 1000);
}
```

But this works on a case-by-case basis, as in some cases the button is disabled even before the function is called the very first time. I want to find a generic solution that works everywhere. Can anyone tell me why this mismatch occurs, and what I can do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you want that? can't you disable after one click and release once your operation done?

Comment: I tried that. It works on a case-by-case basis so far, as sometimes the button is disabled before the function is called the very first time. And it seems that they want to be able to make it generic such that 3 clicks, 4 clicks etc should be disabled, and so maybe that will be an `@Input` attribute to the directive.

Comment: can you disable the button on onClickFunction() instead of using directives?

Comment: I can do that, but the problem would be that I would have to modify an n-number of functions. I preferred to find a generic solution that is easily reusable than changing application logic in multiple places. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I found a solution for this issue. Here is my directive with the updated code.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appPreventDoubleClick]"
})
export class PreventDoubleClickDirective {
  constructor() {}

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  click(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.srcElement.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.srcElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why this works, hope some of you have a better understanding.