# How to use *ngFor and *ngIf in Angular?

Tags: angular

Here I have three `div` which are rendered using `*ngFor`, a `div` has an `image`, `imageName` and `imagesize`.

When the `imageName` extension is wrong (see third `div`) or has no extension (see first) I want to disable the button's `dblclick`. How can I do that?

[image]

```html
<div>
 <mat-card *ngFor="let imagespayload of uploadedImagesObj" (click)="activeFolder=imagespayload"
  (dblclick)="previewFiles(imagespayload.folderid,imagespayload.imageName,imagespayload.urloffolder)"
  (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event,imagespayload)">

  <div *ngIf="getExstendsionIfNotExtension(imagespayload.imageName);else noExtension">
    <img [src]="http://localhost:3000/{{imagespayload.urloffolder}}/{{imagespayload.imageName}}" style="height:40px;width:40px">
    <h3>{{imagespayload.imageName}}</h3>
    <h4>{{imagespayload.imagesize}}</h4>
  </div>

  <ng-template>
    <h5>No Extension of File..</h5>
  </ng-template>
 </mat-card>
</div>
```

```js
public getExstendsionIfNotExtension(image) {
  if(image.endsWith('jpg') || image.endsWith('jpeg') || image.endsWith('gif') || image.endsWith('png') || 
    image.endsWith('tiff') || image.endsWith('tif') || image.endsWith('pdf')) {
     return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Want to disabled div which is not image?

Comment: If you want to disable double click, you might want to use a directive for that.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i want to make disabled (dblclick) button which div image has no extension or wrong image extension

Comment: @theapologist how to use directive for that give me some idea in brief

Comment: @Ankit sure. Do you want to disable single clicks as well or just double clicks?

Comment: @theapologist just double clicks which imageName has no extension or wrong extension of image

Comment: You might have luck checking this thread. I had the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495454/disable-element-attribute-before-onclick-function-is-executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd handle whether or not the event actually does anything in the event handler itself. Thus, I'd write the following:

```html
<div>
  <mat-card *ngFor="let imagespayload of uploadedImagesObj"
    (dblclick)="preview(imagespayload.folderid, imagespayload.imageName, imagespayload.urloffolder)">

    <div *ngIf="hasPreviewableExtension(imagespayload.imageName);else noExtension">
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

```js
public preview(folderid, fileName, urloffolder) {
  if(!this.hasPreviewableExtension(fileName) {
    return;
  }

  // Your code here.
}

public hasPreviewableExtension(fileName) {
  const suffixes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'tiff', 'tif', 'pdf'];
  return suffixes.some(suffix => fileName.endsWith(suffix));
}
```

Note that I did change the names a bit, because this is not only about images, but also PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

In your TS file :

```
public getExstendsionIfNotExtension(image) {
  return image.endsWith('jpg') || image.endsWith('jpeg') || image.endsWith('gif') || image.endsWith('png') || 
    image.endsWith('tiff') || image.endsWith('tif') || image.endsWith('pdf')
}
```

In your template file :

```
<div>
 <mat-card *ngFor="let imagespayload of uploadedImagesObj" (click)="activeFolder=imagespayload"
  (dblclick)="previewFiles(imagespayload.folderid,imagespayload.imageName,imagespayload.urloffolder)"
  (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event,imagespayload)">

  <div *ngIf="getExstendsionIfNotExtension(imagespayload.imageName)">
    <img [src]="http://localhost:3000/{{imagespayload.urloffolder}}/{{imagespayload.imageName}}" style="height:40px;width:40px">
    <h3>{{imagespayload.imageName}}</h3>
    <h4>{{imagespayload.imagesize}}</h4>
  </div>

  <ng-template *ngIf="!getExstendsionIfNotExtension(imagespayload.imageName)">
    <h5>No Extension of File..</h5>
  </ng-template>
 </mat-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `disable` property instead of `*ngIf` on mat-card

```
[disabled]="!getExstendsionIfNotExtension(imagespayload.imageName)'
```

Comment: I use [disabled] in mat-card it gives this type of error Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-card'

Comment: I want to disable only dblclick button

Comment: In that case I think you have to write your click function on div instead on mat-card because as per your code, the image and content will not show if condition true.